# K means clustering on image processing not working

Tags: matlab, image-processing, machine-learning, octave, k-means

I have tried the following code.

```
he = imread('hestain.png');
imshow(he), title('H&E image');
cform = makecform('srgb2lab');
lab_he = applycform(he,cform);
ab = double(lab_he(:,:,2:3));
nrows = size(ab,1); %n rows
ncols = size(ab,2); %p columns
ab = reshape(ab,nrows*ncols,2);

nColors = 3;

[cluster_idx, cluster_center] = kmeans(ab,nColors);
```

It gives me error that

> reshape cannot create a n*p matirx from a n*1 array.

which makes sense but it worked [here](http://in.mathworks.com/help/images/examples/color-based-segmentation-using-k-means-clustering.html).

i tried same kind of code in octave

```
ed=edge(de,"canny");
imshow(ed);
ed=double(ed);
nrows=size(ed,1);
ncols=size(ed,2);
ed=reshape(ed,nrows*ncols,2)
[cluster_idx, cluster_center]=kmeans(ed,3);
pixel_labels = reshape(cluster_idx,nrows,ncols);
imshow(pixel_labels,[]), title('image labeled by cluster index');
```

where de is some image.
when i run i get this error.

> error: reshape: can't reshape 181x181 array to 32761x2 array

help appreciated

Comment: Code works fine for me. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: i have edited please check.

Comment: Try `ed=reshape(ed,nrows*ncols)`

Comment: I tried `ed=reshape(ed,nrows*ncols,1)` then I received this `error: kmeans: empty cluster created` what I am trying to do here is to reduce noise in an image using kmeans clustering.

Comment: I re ran you exact code and the code is working fine. I got the cluster centers as = 161.5429   82.0572, 142.2662  107.5307 and 179.0975   82.8908. Your code looks absolutely fine to me.

Comment: Did you try in octave ? How did you succeed in reshaping a n*m matrix into (n*m)*2 matrix ? How did reshape work for you ?